# Single query for two join statements

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

In plain English, I am trying to find all agents who have a `license` in the state of Ohio and have an `industry` name of Professional Beer...

Here are my models:

```
class Agent < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :phone_number, presence: true
  has_many :licenses
  has_and_belongs_to_many :carriers
end

class Carrier < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :industries
end

class Industry < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :carriers
end

class License < ApplicationRecord
  validates :state, presence: true
  belongs_to :agent
end
```

I have worked out both ends of the queries:

```
2.5.3 :057 > Carrier.joins(:industries).where('industries.name = "Professional Beer Taste-Tester"')
  Carrier Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "carriers".* FROM "carriers" INNER JOIN "carriers_industries" ON "carriers_industries"."carrier_id" = "carriers"."id" INNER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "carriers_industries"."industry_id" WHERE (industries.name = "Professional Beer Taste-Tester") LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Carrier id: 6, name: "Iguana Insure", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, #<Carrier id: 10, name: "Polaris International Risk", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">]>
```

and...

```
2.5.3 :061 > Agent.joins(:licenses).where('licenses.state = "OH"')
  Agent Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "agents".* FROM "agents" INNER JOIN "licenses" ON "licenses"."agent_id" = "agents"."id" WHERE (licenses.state = "OH") LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Agent id: 5, name: "Scot Morar", phone_number: "(279) 691-4148", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, #<Agent id: 6, name: "Cassey Beier", phone_number: "(474) 777-3615", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, #<Agent id: 12, name: "Jani VonRueden", phone_number: "1-444-626-9429", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, #<Agent id: 14, name: "Gemma Ritchie", phone_number: "594.170.4795", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, #<Agent id: 20, name: "Milo Klein", phone_number: "677.137.7019", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, #<Agent id: 40, name: "Ellie Cole", phone_number: "(720) 543-2929", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, #<Agent id: 52, name: "Dayna Hilll", phone_number: "(220) 218-4786", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, #<Agent id: 54, name: "Barton Nikolaus II", phone_number: "1-881-355-1168", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, #<Agent id: 61, name: "Miss Katrice Oberbrunner", phone_number: "1-658-789-4817", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, #<Agent id: 66, name: "Hobert Ryan DDS", phone_number: "501-950-6320", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, ...]>
     => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Carrier id: 6, name: "Iguana Insure", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, #<Carrier id: 10, name: "Polaris International Risk", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">]>
```

Now I need to combine both of these so I am returning a list of agents. So the desired result would return a list of agents:

```
=> [#<Agent id: 118, name: "Deangelo Hermiston", phone_number: "1-756-870-1969", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, #<Agent id: 119, name: "Wm Breitenberg", phone_number: "223-404-1670", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">, #<Agent id: 120, name: "Elsy Vandervort", phone_number: "908.065.9697", created_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30", updated_at: "2019-08-21 15:38:30">]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single query there isn't adequate relations setup. So what can be done is

```
ohio_agents_id = Agent.joins(:licenses).where('licenses.state = "OH"').pluck(:id)
desired_agents = Agent.joins(carriers: :industries).where(industries: { name:  "Professional Beer Taste-Tester" }, id: ohio_agents_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

Below will get desired result in single query

```
Agent.joins(:licenses, carriers: :industries).where('licenses.state = "OH"').where('industries.name = "Professional Beer Taste-Tester"')
```